# C program terminating after creating a few threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

So, I have a project in school in which we need to use C and multithreading etc.. I am a newbie in C, and how pointers work, so I will need your help here. I wrote the program, I execute it, and it creates two or three threads and then says (core dumped). Additionally, I ran it through valgrind, and it obviously has a null pointer, but I cannot solve it. Below is the code and the results when I ran it trough valgrind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5


struct thread_data{
   long  thread_id;
   };

  int SharedVariable = 0;
        void* SimpleThread(void *args) {

        struct thread_data *info = args;
        int num, val;
        for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
        usleep(500);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %ld sees value %d\n", info->thread_id, val);
        SharedVariable = val + 1;
        }
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("Thread %ld sees final value %d\n", info->thread_id, val);


        }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This is part of the valgrind result

```
==12412== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12412== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12412== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12412== Command: ./main
==12412== 
In main: creating thread 0
In main: creating thread 1
In main: creating thread 2
In main: creating thread 3
==12412== Thread 2:
==12412== Invalid read of size 8
==12412==    at 0x4007B3: SimpleThread (in /home/jovan/Desktop/Mttp1/main)
==12412==    by 0x4E3F181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==12412==    by 0x514F47C: clone (clone.S:111)
==12412==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12412== 
==12412== 
==12412== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==12412==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==12412==    at 0x4007B3: SimpleThread (in /home/jovan/Desktop/Mttp1/main)
==12412==    by 0x4E3F181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==12412==    by 0x514F47C: clone (clone.S:111)
==12412==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==12412==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==12412==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==12412==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==12412==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
n main: creating thread 3
==12412== 
==12412== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12412==     in use at exit: 816 bytes in 3 blocks
==12412==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 816 bytes allocated
==12412== 
==12412== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12412==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12412==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12412==      possibly lost: 816 bytes in 3 blocks
==12412==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12412==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12412== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12412== 
==12412== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12412== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Your `main()` doesn't wait for your threads to complete - i.e. it doesn't `join()` them, it just disappears.

Comment: You're casting `t` to a `void *`, which is a bad idea to begin with, but `t` was never initialized in the first place so you're passing a garbage pointer to the thread. Try passing a legitimate pointer value instead.

Comment: Sorry for the bad identation. I was trying to first make it run, then format it. Anyways, @Carey Gregory, how do I fix this? Sorry, It is the first time with C, i am just loosing my virginity with it.

Comment: `struct thread_data *info = args;` You never ever create any object of type `struct thread_data`. `args` cannot possibly point to one. Indeed, `args` is just a thread index cast to `void*`. The only quasi-legitimate thing you can do with it is cast it back to the original `long` type.

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly the answer. Anyway, why do we need to add the pt_join()?

Comment: @DiwakarSharma `t is no more valid` This makes no sense. `t` is an integer. There is no such thing as an integer becoming invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debug using -g option.

```
cc -g test.c 
Run the program and it will generate a core file
gdb ./a.out <core file generated>
When you run under gdb, you will get line number.
```

By running your program, I get this.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004006da in SimpleThread (args=0x1) at thr.c:20
20              printf("*** thread %ld sees value %d\n", info->thread_id, val);
```

You are passing a (void *) converted from an integer. You need to pass the thread_data to the pthread_create.

Here is the modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5


struct thread_data{
   long  thread_id;
   };

int SharedVariable = 0;
        void* SimpleThread(void *args) {

        struct thread_data *info = (struct thread_data *) args;
        int num, val;
        for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
        usleep(500);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %ld sees value %d\n", info->thread_id, val);
        SharedVariable = val + 1;
        }
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("Thread %ld sees final value %d\n", info->thread_id, val);


        }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   struct thread_data td[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, (void *)&td[t]);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

 /* Wait for the threads to end */
 for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
       pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I told him that much in comments. How about showing him *how* to fix it? That's also not the only problem. His `main` is going to terminate before the threads do. How does he fix that?

Comment: Example:   In loop call, before exiting from the main call pthread_join(threads[i], NULL );

Comment: Add the code to your answer, not just here in comments.

Comment: Trying. some problem in editing my answer, particularly the code.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you !!! 
It works perfectly, although i will have to reanalyze everything and try to understand why and where and what happens. My main objective is to learn, not just to solve with help of others.

Comment: @Carey Gregory , why do we have an '&' before td[t] on pthread_create? Does it not point to the memory location instead of the thread value? Thats kind of unclear to me.

Comment: @JovanIvanoski It points to `td[t]` which is exactly what you want.